# Trying to render Froala Editor in React App, but the app crashes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, froala

I'm using React 17 with TypeScript and Webpack 5
and I'm trying to render Froala Editor from 'wysiwyg' package but I get this Error:

```
'FroalaEditorView' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its instance type 'FroalaEditor' is not a valid JSX element.The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types. Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/Al/Desktop/projects/privateLib/node_modules/@types/react-transition-group/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

**Note**: When I'm trying to render the Froala Editor in the app that I generate with CRA, I don't have any issue.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

**Webpack Config:**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const svgrLoader = require.resolve('@svgr/webpack');
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        clean: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
        modules: ['node_modules']
    },
    externals: {
        react: "react"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
                use:['ts-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                type: 'asset',
                resourceQuery: /url/, // *.svg?url
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
                resourceQuery: {not: [/url/]}, // exclude react component if *.svg?url
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: svgrLoader, options: {
                            svgoConfig: {
                                plugins: [
                                    {
                                        name: 'removeViewBox',
                                        active: false
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|)$/,
                type: 'asset/inline',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            FroalaEditor: 'file_name'
        })
    ]
};
```

**TS Config:**

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "types": ["node", "mocha", "jest","cypress", "cypress-file-upload","./cypress/support"],
    "lib": ["es5","es2015","es2016", "dom","esnext"],
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "node_modules/cypress/types/cypress-global-vars.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "**/*.stories.tsx", "**/*.test.tsx"]
}
```

Render Code:

```
<FroalaEditorView
  tag="textarea"
  onModelChange={(newContent: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => props.onChange(newContent)}
  config={textEditorConfig}
  model={props.value}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had the same issue with the `FroalaEditor` component in one of my projects (React 17 and Webpack 5). Although Typescript would complain about the component not being JSX, I could still build and run my application just fine. I managed to please Typescript (get rid of the error) by updating `@types/react`:

```
yarn add @types/react@latest
```

For npm it should be (not 100% sure):

```
npm install –save @types/react
```